# Old Norse: Noun declension gen. sg. -s or -ar?

Tags: dictionary, old-norse, declension

I am using [*A Concise Dictionary of Old Icelandic*](http://norse.ulver.com/dct/zoega/) and *An Introduction to Old Norse* (by E. V. Gordon) as my resoources.

In *An Introduction*, it is said that:

> Some nouns declined otherwise as masculine *a*-stems had the gen. sg. in *-ar*, or ***-s* interchanging with *-ar***, as *skógr*, *smiðr* (nom. pl. *-ir* and *-ar*), vegr...

I don't understand the text in bold at all. Does it mean the gen. sg. ending might be either *-s* or *-ar*, or does it mean something else?

Also, in *A Dictionary*, I find *(-s, -ar)* written right next to noun entries, like this:

> **stigr** or **stígr** (**-s**, **ar**; pl. **-ar**, **-ir**, acc. **-
>   a**, **-u**), m. path.
>   **staurr** (**-s**, **-ar**), m. pale, stake. 
>   **diskr** (**-s**, **-ar**), m. plate, dish.

Is this related to the gen. sg. ending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're interpreting Gordon correctly: these masculines had two variants of the gen. sg. form. The same goes for i-stem masculines: see section 87 (p. 265), "Alternation between *-ar* and *-s* in the gen. sg. was due to partial assimilation to the *a*-stem declension."

Comment: Thanks. What about the (pl. **-ar**, **-ir**, acc. **-a**, **-u**) part in the entry for **stigr**? Are there alternatives for the nom. pl. and the acc. pl. (assuming the latter "acc." is for pl.)?

Comment: I also noticed something about on the *(-s, -ar)* thing; looking at entries such as **söngr**, (**-s**, **-var**) and **hirðir**, (**-is**, **-ar**), I believe the endings in the parentheses mark the gen. sg. and the nom. pl. ending respectively. Also, the entry for **skógr** goes (**-ar**, **-ar**) and that for **smiðr** goes (**-s**, pl. **-ar** and **-ir**).

Comment: I think you must be right about the dictionary; when there are two gen. sg. endings it looks like in some cases, Zoega uses "and": e.g. "vegr (gen. -ar and -s; pl. -ir and -ar, acc. -u and -a)". In other cases (like stigr) he doesn't. But presumably when he says "(-s, -ar)" without a following "pl.", the second ending is the nom. pl. It's not very clear or consistent.